# SQL Sort table with number of iteration from other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, jquery-ui-sortable

i have bank Table and payment table something like these:

```
Bank Table:
BankID/Name
1/bank1Name
2/bank2Name
3/bank3Name
4/bank4Name

Payment Table:
PaymentID/ProductID/BankID
1/100/2
2/102/2
3/98/3
4/100/2
5/102/1
```

as it shows the number of iterated of bank id 2,3,1 are 3,1,1 respectively. I want to sort bank table with most iterated on table bank. the result something like this:

```
2/bank2Name
3/bank3Name
1/bank1Name
4/bank4Name
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what most iterated means but if it is most paymentid something like:

```
select b.bankid, b.name 
from bank b
join payment p
   on b.bankid = p.bankid
group by b.bankid, b.name
order by count(1) desc
```

Another option is to order by a sub-select

```
select b.bankid, b.name  
from bank b 
order by (select count(1) from payment p where b.bankid = p.bankid) desc
```

Answer (score 1):

This is full working example where I am guessing that `bank ids` for each there is no record in the `Payment` table are shown at the end sorted by its id:

```
DECLARE @Bank TABLE
(
     [ID] TINYINT
    ,[Name] NVARCHAR(32)
)

INSERT INTO @Bank ([ID], [Name])
VALUES (1,'bank1Name')
      ,(2,'bank2Name')
      ,(3,'bank3Name')
      ,(4,'bank4Name')
      ,(5,'bank5Name')

DECLARE @Payment TABLE
(
     [PaymentID] TINYINT
    ,[ProductID] TINYINT
    ,[BankID] TINYINT
)

INSERT INTO @Payment ([PaymentID], [ProductID], [BankID])
VALUES (1,100,2)
      ,(2,102,2)
      ,(3,98,3)
      ,(4,100,2)
      ,(5,102,1)


;WITH HelpValue AS
(
    SELECT COUNT([PaymentID]) AS [RoCount]
    FROM @Payment
)
SELECT B.[ID]
      ,B.[Name]
FROM @Bank B
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 P.[PaymentID]
    FROM @Payment P
    WHERE B.[ID] = P.[BankID]
) DS
CROSS APPLY HelpValue
ORDER BY COALESCE(DS.[PaymentID], [RoCount] + B.[ID])
```